# How to draw a point with rectangular/hollow circle marker?

Tags: graphics

Considering that I have some coordinates, now I would like to draw it with a hollow rectangle or circle

```
Graphics[Point[Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/10}]]]
```

[image]

Is there options like `PointStyle -> "Hollow Cirle"/"Hollow Rectangle"/"Solid Rectangle"` for `Point` primitive to let the user specify the corresponding point style?

Comment: `Graphics@Table[Circle[{t, Sin[t]}, 0.1], {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/10}]` or `Graphics@Table[
  Rectangle[{t - 0.05, Sin[t] - 0.05}, {t + 0.05, Sin[t] + 0.05}], {t,
    0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/10}]` or `Graphics@{FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Black], 
  Table[Rectangle[{t - 0.05, Sin[t] - 0.05}, {t + 0.05, 
     Sin[t] + 0.05}], {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/10}]}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to expand on my comment:

It is possible to use any `Graphics` object as the "plot marker" for a function of data points rendered with graphics.

```
Graphics@Table[Circle[{t, Sin[t]}, 0.1], {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/10}]
```

[image]

Where you can use `EdgeForm[]` and `FaceForm[]` to alter the appearance of  objects.

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[{Pink, Opacity[0.8]}], 
  Table[Cuboid[{Sin[t], Cos[t], t}], {t, 0, 4 Pi, Pi/4}]}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

This is a particularly effective way of making interesting looking Graphics.

```
Graphics3D[
 Table[{FaceForm[{ColorData[35][10 t/(4 Pi)], Opacity[0.8]}], 
   Cuboid[{Sin[t], Cos[t], t/2}]}, {t, 0, 4 Pi, Pi/4}], 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: @newer If you mean the wonky looking squares, try `Graphics[Table[
  Rectangle[{t - 0.2, Sin[t] - 0.2}, {t + 0.2, Sin[t] + 0.2}], {t, 0, 
   2 Pi, 2 Pi/10}]]` it's a pixel density issue.

Comment: Your workaround is fine, nice job. However, if the units of the axes are very different, then your circles or rectangles will be distorted. You can scale them, of course. A workaround is to place text "o"s with `Text["o",{t,Sin[t]}]`. Not that I like it. For publishable output you will just need to get the scaling right for the `Circle`s or `Rectangle`s.